# Find the next term using a Forward Difference table

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

I have the sequence **s** and its subsequent difference table:

**s** = 0, 1, 3, 11, 25, 45, 71

$\Delta$ s = 1, 2, 8, 14, 20, 26

$\Delta$^2 s = 1, 6, 6, 6, 6

$\Delta$^3 s = 5, 0, 0, 0

From the difference table we see a pattern in the $\Delta$^2, (second difference), row which is **6**. This informs us that the next term in $\Delta$, the first difference row, is **32** and this in turn tells us that the next term in the sequence **s** is **103**.
Looking at the first column of numbers in the difference table, my thinking was that I could write out the sequence **s** in terms of lowering power basis as follows:

$\mathbf{s} = 0 + \alpha + \frac{\alpha^2}{2} + \frac{5\alpha^3}{6}$

Now we express this in terms of $\alpha$ as follows:

$\mathbf{s} = \alpha + \frac{\alpha(\alpha - 1)}{2} + \frac{5\alpha(\alpha - 1)(\alpha -2)}{6}$ then

$\mathbf{s} = \frac{6\alpha + 3(\alpha^2 - \alpha) + 5(\alpha^3 - 3\alpha^2 + 2\alpha)}{6}$

So for $\alpha = 7$, that is the next term in the sequence **s** we get:

$\mathbf{s} = \frac{42 + 147 - 21 + 1715 - 735 + 70)}{6} = 203$

Hmmm ... its **100** more than what I show when using the table of differences.

Any suggestions as to where I have gone wrong?

Comment: Tip: You can't use MathJax in the quote blocks.

Comment: Thanks ... is there something else I can use to typeset the math symbols?

Comment: Nope, you just have to take them out of the quote blocks.

Comment: Are the quote blocks the indented sections or just the $ signs?

Comment: Indented sections.

Comment: Thanks I will edit to conform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have assumed the third forward difference is *always* $5$, but this is incorrect.  As a consequence, your formula is incorrect starting at $a=4$ (the first term impacted by the $0$ in the third difference).  So, chop off the first term, which does not conform to the subsequent pattern of differences, and try again.

Note that this gives $a$ shifted by $1$, so your formula should start $1 + 2(a-1) + \cdots$.  Then handle $a = 0$ as a line in a piecewise definition  \begin{align*}
a_n = \begin{cases}
0 &, n=0,  \\
1 + 2(n-1) + \cdots &, 0 < n
\end{cases}  \text{.}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank-you that was helpful.